# Return of gift from ex boyfriend

Tags: practical-islam, love

When i as in a relationship he presented me a gold ring. Now we are separated though I don't wear it. I gave it to  my sister , whenever I see that it reminds me of him.

Should I somehow return it to him r what should I do???

Comment: Questions here are expected to be practical and answerable about the topic of Islam, not general calls for advice.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *The answer below is assuming that you didn't have a valid nikah with him and were engaged in Zina.*

The opinion on [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/146086) for a related question is that the gift should be disposed off in charity because it was linked to a forbidden relationship.

> Whatever was taken in return for the haraam relationships that
>   involved the evils that you have mentioned, if it is still with you
>   then you have to get rid of it by giving it to the poor and needy.
>   Whatever has been used up or spent, you do not have to do anything
>   with regard to it.
>
> This is the basic principle with regard to the one who has acquired
>   wealth through haraam work and it was given to him by the other party
>   willingly, such as payment for singing and dancing and the like. **The
>   money should not be given back to the one who gave it, and the one who
>   took it should not benefit from it because it is wealth that he took
>   in an evil manner.**
>
> The gifts that men give in haraam relationships are only given in
>   return for enjoying the continuation of that relationship, seeing the
>   woman, going out with her, talking to her and so on. They are given
>   willingly in return for something haraam. The most correct scholarly
>   opinion on that is what we have mentioned, that one should get rid of
>   them.